# Making an array from few spans text?

Tags: jquery

Is jQuery has a function that can make an array of this spans?

```
<span>text1</span>
<span>text2</span>
<span>text3</span>
<span>text4</span>
```

for example if I'll use this

```
var arr = jQuery.('span').text(); // it should be simple string text1text2text3text4
```

but I need

```
arr[0]='text1';
arr[1]='text2';
arr[2]='text3';
arr[3]='text4';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/) to do this

```
var arr = jQuery('span').map(function () {
    return $.trim(this.innerHTML);
}).get();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2UunB/)

Answer (score 0):

its more smarter, cause you are not mixing javascript and jQuery syntax :)

```
    var arr = jQuery('span').map(function () {
        return $.trim($(this).val());
    }).get();
    console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var spanArray = $("span");
var stringArray = [];

for(var i = 0; i<spanArray.length; i++){
   stringArray.push($(spanArray[i]).text());
}
```

[Here is a working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5rgXx/3/)